# Qt5 for Android: Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: quick qml

Tags: android, qml, qt5, qt-necessitas

I built Qt5 for Android with the step by step tutorial from this link:
[Building Qt 5 for Android](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt5ForAndroidBuilding).

Now, i'm able to build and deploy QWidget Applications to my nexus 7. But if i try to build a QtQuick Application with the given template of QtCreator 2.7.1, i get the following error:

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: quick qml
```

I did every build step exactly as described in the tutorial. Has anybody else faced this error?

Comment: I think qt quick was not officially supported on Android before Qt5.1. Did you try with the latest version?

Comment: i had same problem,solution was to create new project and copy files from old one, after that everything worked.

Comment: @Frime: have you fixed it? It works here with 5.1.1

Answer (score 3):

QtQuick works perfectly well with Qt5.2. My suggestion is that you built Qt5.2 from source, instead of simply installing it, i.e. you clone it from [Gitorious](http://wiki.qt.io/Building-Qt-5-from-Git). After you check all the details, once you put it to build, go for a coffee as it will take a while to finish it.

Also, have you installed the Android SDK and NDK? If not, my suggestion is that you install the [Studio Android](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

You will also have to be very careful in making all the environment setups for your cross-compiling tool-chain otherwise it will not work. Check in the sequence what I have for my development settings.

[image]

Ant is also part of the installation, as you probably won't wish to miss that.

[image]

In the end if you have done all the settings accordingly, without forgetting anything, then you just need to select Qt Quick Application.

[image]

And it will work, as qt quick is officially supported on Android Qt5.2.